# python doesn't print in same line with end = '' after number

Tags: python

I've made a program that makes a random change to a number every 10th of a second, and I want the new number to be printed in the same line as before. However, it just prints nothing when I add "end = '' " to the print command.
Here's my code:

```
import random, time

stock = 1000000

while True:
    change = random.randint(0, 10)
    operation = random.randint(0, 1)

    if operation == 0:
        stock -= change
    else:
        stock += operation
        
    print(stock, change, end = ' ')

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you would want to use

```py
print(stock, change, end = '\r')
```

Answer (score 1):

add flush=True and sep=' ' in your print function. That will make sure the print dynamically in one line.
e.g

```
print(stock, change, sep=' ', end='', flush=True)
```